# C# toggle boolean within a loop / Unity toggle boolean in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, toggle

The title may look inconclusive, but it's the same thing, it's just explained differently when talking about the Unity engine, just in case any Unity vets are to see my post.

In the Unity engine, there are certain methods that do specific tasks within a class, one of these is the `Update()` method, which loops for every frame (hence the loop expression in the title).

The idea is that I will have an expression inside this loop, waiting for the user to click a key, which would in turn toggle a boolean variable.
I've tried to implement this in a number of different ways, but the way I'm doing it now seems the most promising.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Delete))
{
    if (this.modGodspeed)
    {
        this.speedMult = 1f;
        this.godSpeedToggled = "OFF";
        this.modGodspeed = false;
    }
    if (!this.modGodspeed)
    {
        this.speedMult = 5f;
        this.godSpeedToggled = "ON";
        this.modGodspeed = true;
    }
}
```

During the startup the boolean is initialized to false, so it says `OFF` by default, and when I click the delete key the first part of this works, and it shows `ON` and the `speedMult` variable is set to 5. The problem is that it does not toggle off again. Clicking 'delete' again does nothing.

Code description:

`Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Delete)` = Part of the Unity library, reads key input.

`modGodSpeed` = Boolean I'm talking about.

`speedMult` = Speedmultiplier to be toggled.

`godSpeedToggled` = String variable, shows the user whether godspeed is toggled or not.

Comment: Instead of second if use else. Your second if triggers just after first is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you wrote.

This is what is happening:

**1**.`if (this.modGodspeed)` will execute and set `modGodspeed` to `false`.

**2**. `if (!this.modGodspeed)` below it will execute in the-same frame and set `modGodspeed` to `true`.

**3**.This will repeat when you press the delete key `(KeyCode.Delete)` again.

---

**#2** shouldn't execute if the first `if` statement executes. You need to  make the `if` statement to check only once so that if the  `modGodspeed` variable is `true`, the other `if` statement below it **won't** be checked again. This is why there is an `if`, `else if` and `else` statements.

Use else `if` in your second `if` statement:

```
if (this.modGodspeed)
{
    ....
}
else if (!this.modGodspeed)
{
    ...
}
```

Or simply use the `else` statement since the `modGodspeed` variable is a boolean variable which can either be `true` or `false`.

```
if (this.modGodspeed)
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I made this mistake :^)

Comment: No problem and you are welcome. I think it's worth explaining.